# brake pedal sinks to floor when vehicle is started

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, tahoe, hydroboost

I have an 06 Tahoe LT and had a fluid leak close to the fire wall. After some research I found out that the hydrobooster seal is susceptible to leaks after some time. I ordered and replaced the seal. Once everything was installed back I pressed the brake pedal and it seems to be normal when the vehicle is off. When I start the vehicle the brake pedal goes straight to the floor board without being pressed, also there is a whining sound and it is very hard to turn the steering wheel left to right. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your Hydroboost gets power off of the power steering pump. Refill the reservoir with Dexron tranny fluid and it should be fine.

You'll need to bleed the power steering. To do that, the front end should be jacked up with the front tires off the ground. Fill the reservoir, then with the engine running, rotate the steering wheel back and forth several times, lock to lock. Then check the fluid, top off, and repeat until it stays up to level.